# How to enable Autoscaling group in us-west-2 to access SQS in us-east-1 via VPC peering connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

I am trying to expand my current aws application. My application is based entirely in us-east-1 and it includes Lambda functions, sqs , autoscaling groups and a database.
Recently we have used up a lot of gpu's in the current region and aws team suggested we consider using gpu's in us west 2.
So I have created a VPC in us west 2 and started a peering connection to the vpc in us east 1. All I want to do is that my Autoscaling group in west2 can send and receive messages from sqs in us east 1.
How do I navigate this and are there some documents around this(I couldn't find any)?

I tried creating a vpc peering connection but don't know how to navigate setting up security groups and endpoints.

Comment: All you need to do is set the region/endpoint in your SQS connection code to us-east-1. Would need to see your code, or at least know the programming language you are using, to provide more details.

Comment: Hey @MarkB , I was able to find a better solution using IAM policies. I assigned policies to allow resources to receive and send messages to sqs in another region and also update sqs policy to allow traffic from certain resources.

Comment: That's not a "better option" it's just the permissions you needed to assign in order allow the API calls. My comment was about performing the actual API calls. Your question was vague as far as what problems you were actually running into and needed help with.